# How to "echo" a text in EJS (a javascript template) to check a radio button

Tags: javascript, radio-button, ejs

I need help
I'm using EJS javasript template to write a code snippet two check a radio button depending on data returned from the server. Let say the server returns a json (named my_data) and here is my code

```
<input type="radio" name="is_public" value=1 <% if(my_data.is_public){ %> <%='checked' %> <% } %> />Public
<input type="radio" name="is_public" value=0 <% if(!my_data.is_public){ %> <%='checked' %> <% } %> />Private
```

But it doesnt work! the Public is always checked although my_data.is_public = 0.

Any one can help?

btw, are there the way to "echo" a text like this in EJS:

```
<input type="radio" name="is_public" value=1 <% if(my_data.is_public){ echo 'checked' } %> />Public
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never used EJS, but from experience from other templating engines, this should work:

```
<input type="radio" name="is_public" value=1 <% if(my_data.is_public){ %> checked="checked" <% } %> />Public
<input type="radio" name="is_public" value=0 <% if(!my_data.is_public){ %> checked="checked" <% } %> />Private
```

When you say `<%=`, you are to output the result of a JavaScript evaluation that follows. E.g. `<%= a %>` should output the contents of variable `a` at that time.

There's no need for explicit echo in templates - anything outside `<% %>` should be echoed by default, of course considering that some blocks are conditionally echoed, like the above `if`, or may be multiplied when using loops, etc.

Comment: I solved it. It seems Javascript does not know 1 as true and 0 as false. So when I change the if condition as follow: if(my_data.is_public == 1) instead if(my_data.is_public) and if(my_data.is_public == 0) instead if(!my_data.is_public), it works :D
anyway thanks for your advice. My code is now cleaner when I removed <%= %> :D

Comment: Glad to help!. Javascript itself does this - see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CdPbp/. This might be EJS-specific. Anyway, what you found out should work just fine.

Comment: @LeoLerdorf , this works for almost every language. The actual "boolean" false, is in fact 0, null, nil, {}, [], or anythings that is empty (in JS). Try this: `console.log(10*false);` and `console.log(10*true);` and you will understand it ;)

Answer (score 8):

EJS is a simple and easy to use engine, and does not need to put too much learning cost on the template. If you look at [the source](https://github.com/mde/ejs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=__append&type=), you'll find something funny.

```
// the same as echo string
__append(string)
```

So:

```
<input type="radio" name="is_public" value=1 <% if(my_data.is_public){ __append('checked') } %> />Public
```

Comment: Agree! It can be useful when you need to insert some text within your ejs code without braking it by ejs tags. So JS code becomes more clear. Thanks a lot.